# Hide specific Shopify Page on search engines

Tags: shopify, liquid, robots.txt

I have pages I want to hide on search engines. I successfully hide those pages on Google, however, it is still showing on Bing and Yahoo engines.

What do I need to do to hide those pages on all search engines?

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/seo/editing-robots-txt

Answer (score 1):

From your **Shopify admin**, go to **Online Store > Themes**.

Find the theme you want to edit, click the ... button to open the actions menu, and then click Edit code.

Click the **theme.liquid** layout file.

To exclude the search template, paste the following code in the  section:

```
{% if template contains 'search' %}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```

To exclude a specific page, paste the following code in the  section:

```
{% if handle contains 'page-handle-you-want-to-exclude' %}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```

Make sure that you replace page-handle-you-want-to-exclude with the correct page handle.

Click Save.

More
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/seo/hide-a-page-from-search-engines

Comment: I already did this {% if handle contains 'page-handle-you-want-to-exclude' %}
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %} but it only hides in google search engines not in Bing and Yahoo.

Comment: @Len Bing and Yahoo respects noindex meta rule. Give it some time to refresh :)